# Variable change to eliminate mixed partial derivatives in a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I want to apply a variable change to eliminate the mixed partial derivatives in the following equation:
$${u_{t}} - {u_{txx}} - {u_{xx}} = 0$$
I used the method from the answer to this question: [PDE with mixed derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2339227/pde-with-mixed-derivative)

However, at least with that variable change, the method doesn't work.

Can someone tell me the correct change or point me in the direction of a more appropriate method to deal with this pde?

The boundary conditions that I'm interested in are
$${u_{x}}= 0 \quad \text{at} \quad x=0 \quad \text{for} \quad t>0$$
and
$$u= 1 \quad \text{at} \quad x=1\quad \text{for} \quad t>0$$
with the initial condition of
$$u=0 \quad \text{at} \quad t=0 \quad \text{for} \quad 0<x<1$$

Comment: In this case there is no linear invertible change of coordinates that eliminates the terms with mixed derivatives (just checked)

Comment: So what would be the appropriate method to solve it then?

Comment: It depends on the domain you want, the boundary conditions you want,… If you are looking for solutions in the whole $\mathbb R^2$ or on, say, $\mathbb R\times (0,T)$, you could use the Fourier transform.

Comment: I edited the question to include the BCs and IC. I'm interested in a finite domain solution.

Comment: In this case I would suggest to use the fourier series method. Or the separation of variables method, which is ultimately the same thing. Try to look online for the application of these methods in standard models, e.g., the heat equation or the wave equation. There’s surely plenty of material on that stuff. Then you can try to reproduce the same technique for this equation.

Comment: Small note: your initial condition doesn’t appearently seem to be consistent with the boundary condition at $x=1$. Maybe you actually want that, but that could lead to very low regularity of the solution